# How to handle exceptions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I started to learn Kotlin and I can't understand how to handle exceptions. I know there's no checked ones, but anyway, what should I do if my method throws one? For example:

```
fun test(a: Int, b: Int) : Int {
    return a / b
}
```

If I divide by zero, I will have ArithmeticException. So how should I handle such things?

Comment: `try-catch` works pretty much the same way as it does in Java. You can see it in the docs about exceptions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html).

Comment: @zsmb13 So it's like I can handle "checked" exceptions, just don't write throws in method signature? And it's ok to write like that? If so, pls write it as answer and I will close this question.

Comment: return Try<Int> so that client can call isSuccess or isFailure
http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2017/12/kotlin-try-type-for-functional.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) is a runtime exception, so it would be unchecked in Java as well. Your choices for handling it are the same as in Java too:

- Ignore it and get a crash at runtime
- Wrap it with a `try-catch` block. You catch it anywhere up the stack from where it happens, you don't need any `throws` declarations.

Since there are no checked exceptions in Kotlin, there isn't a `throws` keyword either, but if you're mixing Kotlin and Java, and you want to force exception handling of checked exceptions in your Java code, you can annotate your method with a [`@Throws`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-throws/index.html) annotation.

See the official Kotlin docs about exceptions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html).

Answer (score 18):

You may write an extension function to return a default value when encounting exception.

```
fun <T> tryOrDefault(defaultValue: T, f: () -> T): T {
    return try {
        f()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        defaultValue
    }
}

fun test(a: Int, b: Int) : Int = tryOrDefault(0) {
    a / b
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As a plus since try-catach in kotlin can return values your code could look like this:

```
fun test(a: Int, b: Int) : Int {
    return try {a / b} catch(ex:Exception){ 0 /*Or any other default value*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return Try so that client can call isSuccess or isFailure
http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2017/12/kotlin-try-type-for-functional.html

You can also return Int? so that client will know that the value might not exist (when divided by zero).